# How to add elements to expandable menu?

Tags: android

I want to have an expandable menu, and when you expand a child item, then it will show some custom items, items of my choice, like a text input field or a checkbox (see the image below).

Now how can I achieve that? Can I achieve that using the Eclipse GUI builder? Or do I have to create methods where the data is loaded dynamically?

[image: image of expandable menu with custom items]

### UPDATE:

So I do not only want text items as child elements, but all sorts of elements, like an input field or checkbox.

Comment: Take a look at writing custom list adapters this will give you the functionality your looking for

Comment: I am looking for the exact same thing. Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial works like charm

http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/08/android-expandable-list-example.html

i also took code from here to make my custom expandable UI by implementing adapter